# %Name% can't get the file name in model builder for Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

When I try to use %Name% to get the shp name, I get the wrong name. The result is "%Name%.tif".

It seems like can't get the right name. How can i fix it?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The chinese charaters could be use to name the file.  The "%NAME%" used to be work in 2 days ago. Now, it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved. We should notice that the file path do not have charater like"%" or"_" etc.